# Angular2 HostListener check URL change

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a navbar component that is called in every pages of my website.
I want it to check when the URL change with a HostListener.

```
@HostListener('window:hashchange', ['$event'])
onHashChange(event) {
    this.checkCurrentURL();
}  

private checkCurrentURL(){
    console.log("loaction : "+window.location.pathname)
}
```

However it doesn't work. 
Any ideas ?

**EDIT**: SOLUTION

The solution I found is without HostListener, but it works.

```
constructor(private router : Router){
 router.events.subscribe((val) => {
  this.checkCurrentURL();
 });
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you're trying to do? You show youre trying to listen to the hashchange event, which only fires when the hash is actually changed, not the path.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a HostListener for this. Assuming you are developing a single page app, you wanna subscribe to route change event.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Answer (score 1):

As Angular is Single page Application , 
so you can define a global variable **window** in one of the component  and using window global variable  we can track each and every route ,   ,

> window.location.href

**window.location.href** will return the current Url , and thus we can check when the URL change

```
constructor(private router : Router){
 router.events.subscribe((val) => {
    console.log(window.location.href); 
 });
}
```